# Django break statement not allowed in block tags

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

Error message: "django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 82: 'break', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

This error is being caused because I am trying to use the `break` statement in a block tag in a Django template.

To fix this error, I  replace it with a `return` statement from the block tag. Which will terminate the `if` statement immediately. But the error remains the same.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="card">
                <h5 class="mb-30">By Categories</h5>
                <div class="categories-dropdown-wrap font-heading">
                  <ul>
                    {% for c in categories %}
                      <li>
                        <input
                          data-filter="category"
                          class="form-check-input filter-checkbox"
                          type="checkbox"
                          name="checkbox"
                          id="exampleCheckbox2"
                          value="{{ c.id }}"
                        />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="{% url 'core:category-product-list' c.cid %}">
                          <img src="{{c.image.url}}" alt="" />{{ c.title }}</a
                        >
                      </li>
                      {% if c.loop.index == 5 %}
                        <li>
                          <p>This is the 5th category.</p>
                        </li>
                        {% break %}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
```

My goal is to stop the for loops after listing 5 items from the category, Please I need help to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

@Tarquinius
Thanks, Boss
I find another method to solve it using *slice*
instead to limit my iterations, then trim the number of entries being added in the context from the views.py. I return a slice of the list with this, I can limit it to a few places, not the entire function for example the category list on the sidebar can now have only 5 items while the category list page has the full list.

here is the updated code:

```
<div class="card">
                <h5 class="mb-30">By Categories</h5>
                <div class="categories-dropdown-wrap font-heading">
                  <ul>
                    {% for c in categories|slice:":5" %}
                      <li>
                        <input
                          data-filter="category"
                          class="form-check-input filter-checkbox"
                          type="checkbox"
                          name="checkbox"
                          id="exampleCheckbox2"
                          value="{{ c.id }}"
                        />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="{% url 'core:category-product-list' c.cid %}">
                          <img src="{{c.image.url}}" alt="" />{{ c.title }}</a
                        >
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
```

ref [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

Comment: I agree, looks like the cleaner option!

Answer (score 0):

This would be one option:
`arr = ["tool1", "tool2", ... , "tool10"]`

```html
{% for tool in arr %}
  {% if forloop.revcounter0 <= 4 %}
    {{ tool }}
  {% else %}
    <!--empty-->
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Basically what this code is doing is not to break the for-loop but just input "nothing" when the condition is not met. Another phrasing: After iterating five times it is not inserting the variable anymore and inserts "nothing" instead.

You now might want to argue: "It would be more efficient to break the loop instead of continuing the iteration process while inserting nothing". Yes, I agree. But to make this more efficient your way to go here is to cut the length of the list already to an appropriate length inside of your view before passing it to the template. As far as I know there is no way of breaking out of a loop within djangos templating language.

`{% break %}` is not a built-in keyword within djangos templating language so it will by default always end up as a syntax error. So the error is not related to the fact that you put it inside of a `{% block ... %}` tag.

Read more about the [`forloop.revcounter0`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)